# Which terminal does Ubuntu use?

Tags: command-line

I've recently moved to Linux Mint, but I've always preferred the Ubuntu terminal over the xterm that is used in XFCE and KDE, can anyone tell me what it is called or where I can download it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`gnome-terminal`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gnome-terminal)

Comment: Too stark for my amusement. :'(

Answer (score 5):

Ubuntu uses Gnome Terminal by default. Xfce uses xfce4-terminal. KDE uses Konsole.

Answer (score 1):

in LXDE it uses the lxde-terminal or some such variant.
in kde konsole(usually).
but there is also the TTY which I would recommend for fun(as in it does not allow you to focus on more than one thing at once). press ctrl-alt-F1-f6 ctrl-alt-F7 to exit.