# Gnome-terminal vs Ubuntu-terminal differences?

Tags: command-line, gnome, gnome-terminal, xfce

I am using Xfce4 and I have two terminals on my system. The first one is Gnome-terminal.

[image]

And the second one is Ubuntu-terminal (???) which can be started like **terminal** from the first one.

[image]

As one can see, they differ in interface and performance (Ubuntu terminal is more sluggish).
What I do not know is whether they have any functional differences?

All checkup commands according to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/640096/how-do-i-check-which-terminal-i-am-using) shows first terminal as **gnome-terminal**, and the second one as simply **terminal**. If [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112052/which-terminal-does-ubuntu-use) is correct and Ubuntu uses gnome-terminal by default then why I have two? And what is the second one?

P.S. It is **not** xfce4-terminal, as one can suggest.

Comment: Open a terminal and run `xprop`. The cursor should turn into a crosshair. Place this crosshair over the same terminal window and click. Details of the terminal will be listed. Do the same with the other terminal. See if you can find any relevant info.

Comment: I tried and it showed me nothing more than I described above. The first one  is gnome terminal and the second one shows `ubuntu-terminal-app` in WM_CLASS(STRING). I am interested in their feature differences, there is very little info about this ubuntu-terminal.

Comment: It's probably this then: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-terminal-app the one created for Ubuntu Touch.

Comment: Okay, wiki entry for this app [is absent](https://developer.ubuntu.com/community/core-apps/terminal). It seems to be just a wrapper for gnome-terminal?